# generar el numero primo mas grande posible Actualmente el número primo más grande tiene 22338618 dígitos

Tags: java-ee

```
 int limite =Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int i = 1; i < limite; i++) {
            boolean isPrimeNumber = true;
// verificamos si el numero es primo 
            for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {

                if (i % j == 0) {
                    isPrimeNumber = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
// imprimir el numero si es P 
            if (isPrimeNumber) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

tengo este codigo para generar numeros primos pero necesito generar numeros primos grandes de 22338618 dígitos.  y nose si con mi codigo pueda hacerlo alguien que me ayude con mi problema para hacer un codigo mas eficiente.

Comment: Mira al final del video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xp7Spuj8XlI (el código echo); tambien puedes agregar un archivo donde tengas "n" numeros primos y en vez de un for de 1 a n-1 dividir el N por cada numero primo que tengas (en el archivo) y si da su residuo 0 entonces no es primo.

Answer (score 2):

la clase `biginteger` sirve para manejar cantidades muy grandes y tiene un una función para generar posibles primos `probablePrime`

```
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Genprime {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      BigInteger primo;
      int bitLength = 1050; 
      Random rnd = new Random();
      primo = BigInteger.probablePrime(bitLength, rnd);
      String str = "primo probable: "+primo;
      System.out.println( str );
   }
}
```

primo probable: 7800818706943658241580291849017184232232760537621784861990999178101828122213625111952122322821576517708603074148015450441432678806530959526437941711831826348342555055552398056351539789423440679594205486233425048980255599193903435930841478380364053227466004304175853593949962198378139117420235838875605761365875967039

Entre mas grande sea `bitLength` mas grande sera el numero, pero tardara mas en generarse.